# É uma má prática utilizar uma variável "opcional" dentro de um objeto?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Quando vou baixar uma foto no meu sistema, o processo de download passa por um método de segurança que me retorna um objeto chamado `DownloadResponse`.

```
public class DownloadResponse{
    public bool IsValid{get; set; }
    public int DownloadTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

Dentro dele eu tenho o `IsValid` e o `DownloadTypeID`, DownloadTypeID pode tanto retornar 1 quanto 2, 1 para download e 2 para *re-download*.

Quando o valor for 2 eu precisaria retornar um valor do meu banco chamado `license-key` porém eu queria inserir esse `license-key` dentro do retorno desse meu objeto inserindo uma variável "opcional":

```
public class DownloadResponse{
    public bool IsValid{get; set; }
    public int DownloadTypeID { get; set; }
    public string LicenseKey { get; set; } //Só tera valor quando o DownloadTypeID == 2
}
```

É correto eu fazer isso nesse tipo de situação? Fico na duvida se não fere algum conceito de orientação a objetos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu falo muito sobre [má prática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20m%C3%A1%20pr%C3%A1tica). Falo o quanto isto quer dizer pouco ou nada. Tem que fazer o que precisa para atender a necessidade da melhor forma possível. Isto varia de caso para caso.

Consegue pensar em outra solução melhor que não faça isso?

Eu penso em uma que tem tipos diferentes (provavelmente herdados de uma base comum) dependendo do estado de outra variável, o que na prática fará esta propriedade desaparecer destes tipos já que o tipo já indicaria o que teria em seu valor. Isto resolve a questão de ter uma variável com um dado nulo (opcional). É questionável se isso é melhor ou não.

Os mais puristas vão dizer que tem que fazer assim. Os mais pragmáticos vão dizer que não é bem assim e pode complicar a aplicação sem necessidade.

Em um banco de dados dá para fazer tudo como `NOT NULL`, mas pode complicar a modelagem. É a mesma coisa. Entenda que só terá um nulo ali em `LicenseKey`.

Não fere nada de OO, e se ferir mas resolver bem seu problema, que fira. Um dos erros que se comete é achar que basta seguir uma metodologia específica e tudo ficará lindo. Fazer certo é o que importa e isto nenhuma metodologia diz como é em cada caso.

Pode ter algum problema para o seu caso, mas nada a ver com orientação a objeto.

Note que o fato de ter um nulo passa fazer parte da definição do seu domínio.
Você precisa saber que só pode pegar esta informação verificando se ela está válida. Isso pode até ser abstraído no próprio objeto. Se fizessem objetos diferentes haveria a garantia que está sempre válido, mas teria que tratar tudo de forma diferente para cada tipo, teria método que saber lidar um o objeto que tem uma chave e outro que sabe lidar com o objeto que não tem.

Eu não sou fã de nada nulo, e por sorte C# 8 deve permitir evitar seu uso. Mas há casos que o nulo faz muito sentido. Em C# 8 ficará interessante porque mesmo onde precisa ser nulo o compilador te obrigará tratar adequadamente.

Em C# 8 pode ser interessante fazer assim:

```
public class DownloadResponse{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public int DownloadTypeID { get; set; }
    public string? LicenseKey { get; set; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Nullable.cs).

Comment: Vou fazer assim então ! Obrigado pela ótima resposta como sempre.

Comment: Eu poderia criar um outro objeto de resposta com a LicenseKey porém acho que ia ficar mais complexo do que a LinceseKey sendo nula em alguns casos.

Comment: É, tudo será mais complicado, não vejo ganhos de nenhum tipo. Eu não upei a pergunta porque acabaram meus votos hj.